# Prove that every sum of squares in $K$ is a square in $K$, where $K$ is certain field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field such that $f(t)=t^{2}+1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $K[t]$. Let $i$ be a root of $f$ in an algebraic closure of $K$. Suppose every element of $K(i)$ is a square in $K(i)$. Prove that every sum of squares in $K$ is a square in $K$.

Comment: you tried something?

Comment: Hint: $a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$.

Comment: I have tried to prove it by contradiction. All I have got is that, if there exists an element of $K$ which is a sum of squares but not a square, then -1 is a sum of squares in $K$. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: every element is a square of $K(i)$. So $a+ib=c^2$ and $a-ib=d^2$. Now the product $cd$ is...

Comment: It should very easy with your hints, but I still don't get it. I must be missing something.